# Gnuplot Line Color in HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) Model

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot to draw a simple function like this

```
plot cos(x) lc rgb "red"
```

How can I specify the line color using HSV model by providing Hue, Saturation and Value (brightness).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In gnuplot 5.0, we can use the hsv2rgb function to convert hsv values to rgb (later in this post, we will write this function for earlier versions).  This function takes all three parameters in the range 0-1 and returns a rgb integer.

Demonstrating this, we can do

```
set samples 100
set xrange[0:10]
set style fill solid
unset key
plot '+' u 1:(sin($1)):(hsv2rgb($1/10.0,1,1)) with boxes lc rgbcolor variable
```

to produce

[image]

showing the hue, and

```
plot '+' u 1:(sin($1)):(colorval(120/360.0,1,$1/10.0)) with boxes lc rgbcolor variable
```

to produce

[image]

showing the value.

To use this function to select line color, we can just do

```
plot x lc rgbcolor hsv2rgb(90/360.0,0.8,0.3)
```

producing

[image]

---

In gnuplot 4.6, this function does not exist, but we can write our own, using the formulas from [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV) on the hsv system.

```
chroma(h,s,v) = v * s
hprime(h) = h/60.0
fmod2(x) = (x>2)?(x - 2*floor(x/2.0)):x
xprime(h,s,v) = chroma(h,s,v) * ( 1 - abs(fmod2(hprime(h)) - 1))
rprime(h2,h,s,v) = (h2<1)?chroma(h,s,v):(h2<2)?xprime(h,s,v):(h2<4)?0:(h2<5)?xprime(h,s,v):chroma(h,s,v)
gprime(h2,h,s,v) = (h2<1)?xprime(h,s,v):(h2<3)?chroma(h,s,v):(h2<4)?xprime(h,s,v):0
bprime(h2,h,s,v) = (h2<2)?0:(h2<3)?xprime(h,s,v):(h2<5)?chroma(h,s,v):xprime(h,s,v)
mprime(h,s,v) = v - chroma(h,s,v)
red(h,s,v) = rprime(hprime(h),h,s,v) + mprime(h,s,v)
green(h,s,v) = gprime(hprime(h),h,s,v) + mprime(h,s,v)
blue(h,s,v) = bprime(hprime(h),h,s,v) + mprime(h,s,v)
colorval(h,s,v) = (floor(red(h,s,v)*255)*2**16) + (floor(green(h,s,v)*255)*2**8) + floor(blue(h,s,v)*255)
hsv2rgb(h,s,v) = colorval(h*360.0,s,v)
```

This function works the same as the gnuplot 5.0 built-in function.  We need the custom modulus function as gnuplot can't calculate modulus division with floating point values.  We compute the red, green, and blue components in the range from 0-255 and then pack them into an integer value.

Comment: awesome: I had no idea `hsv2rgb()` existed, so this just saved me a bunch of lines setting up a custom `palette model`, hiding its `colorbox`, etc.